# database is locked while inserting data ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

Right now I am **inserting** into the db on the basis of count. If count is greater than zero than **"SELECT"** will run and my data will be shown, else **"INSERT"** will take place. Right now my db is empty so the condition goes to **"INSERT"** section and in that I am getting "Database is Locked:ERROR". i have gone through some examples and it said like we have to **finalize** the curent query before starting the new one. I have done that thing too but still my problem is same. Posting my code here :

```
 if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                              @"SELECT count(*) FROM tables WHERE table_id='%d'",
                              table_id];
        NSLog(@"fetch query is....  %@",querySQL);
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *countstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &countstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSLog(@"FEtch");
            sqlite3_step(countstmt);

            rows = sqlite3_column_int(countstmt, 0);
            NSLog(@"no of rows is %d",rows);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
           }
    if(rows>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"NO of rows is : %d",rows);
        //if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
       // {

        NSString *querySQQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"SELECT * FROM tables WHERE table_id='%d'",
                               table_id];
        NSLog(@"fetch query is....  %@",querySQQL);
        const char *query_stmmt = [querySQQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB,
                               query_stmmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"yes...");

        }
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            //int i=0;
            NSLog(@"yesssss...");
            // NSInteger count = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);
            //NSLog(@"Rowcount is %d",(long)count);
            table_data= [[NSString alloc]
                         initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            status= [[NSString alloc]
                     initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            row_id= [[NSString alloc]
                     initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            table_idd= [[NSString alloc]
                        initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
            //searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:namee];
            NSString *finalarrayy;
            //for(loop=1;loop<=z;loop++)
            //{
            finalarrayy=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@",row_id,table_data,status,table_idd];
            [stringArray addObject:table_data];
            NSLog(@"Array....is...%@",stringArray);

        }
        [defaults setObject:stringArray forKey:@"stringarray"];
        [defaults synchronize];
           //}
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }




    else{
        NSLog(@"INsert");
        //if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        // {
        for(i=mn; i<=o ; i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=19;j++)

            {
                k=i*j;
                NSString *val=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d   %@   %d   %@   %d",i,@"x",j,@"=",k];
                //tab_data.value=val;
                [stringArray addObject:val];
                NSString *insertSQLL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                        @"INSERT INTO tables(table_data,status,table_id) VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%d')",
                                        val,@"NO",table_id];
                NSLog(@"sql stm. is ..%@",insertSQLL);


                const char *insert_stmtt = [insertSQLL UTF8String];
                sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmtt,
                                   -1, &statement, NULL);
                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"yes");
                }
                else
                {

                    NSLog(@"Error: failed to insert into the database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(_contactDB));

                }

            }
        }

   // }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);

    }
```

PLease tell me what is wrong with my code. The code is running for the first time like if nothing is in the database then values are inserting into the db but for the second time if I want to insert something new  into the db then its throwing error"database is locked".Actually I am running the same code in **viewdidload** and on the action of **segmentcontrol**. For **viewdidload** it is running fine but in the case of **segmentcontrol** it is creating error, any idea regarding this. If someone can modify my code I will be very thankful to him/her.

Comment: I think you are not copying the database file into NSDocumentDirectory

Comment: @TENSRI...nop everything is perfect..db is already created..but values are not inerting into db

Answer (score 0):

> you must always close the sqlite database after using it ... so add this line sqlite3_close(DB); just after sqlite3_finalize(statement);

Comment: @ muhammad Waqas it is not neccessary to close the db every time.. I m damn sure abt that